# How to call a function which returns a number in Drawer item using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show the number of each item in Drawer Item in react native. for this purpose I created a function which returns the number of items I want. But it does not give me what I want. How can I call this function in Drawer Item title?

function:

```
const countItems = async () => {
  const storedArray = await  AsyncStorage.getItem('fav_data').then(favs => {
    const count = JSON.parse(favs).length;
    return count;
   
   
  })
  // console.log(storedArray)
  return storedArray;
   
}
```

and here I want to call it:

```
<DrawerItem title={'test ' + countItems()} accessoryLeft={HeartIcon}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Favorites')}/>
```

Comment: you are using both `.then` and `async / await` syntax together and there is no need for a extra .then callback . simply await your `Async storage` and this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `await`ing the result of countItems, so it will return `undefined` at render time. Since the number isn't stored in state, changes to the number won't trigger a re-render of the screen.

Here's an example of the most common way to solve this problem: with state and effect hooks.

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('fav_data').then(favs => {
    const count = JSON.parse(favs).length;
    setCount(count);   
  })
}, []);

...

<DrawerItem
  title={count ?? 'Loading'}
  accessoryLeft={HeartIcon}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Favorites')}
/>
```

The useEffect hook has an empty dependency array (the 2nd argument), so it will only run once, on the mount of the component.

If you want to read more about the state and effect hooks, sections 3 and 4 of the following React doc have good explanations: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html